# Do I really need a Mac to develop applications for iPad

Tags: ipad, development-environment

I would like to start developing an application for iPad Air. For this do I really need another Apple product, like iMac on Mac Book?

SK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legally speaking yes, the only way how to compile iOS app is Xcode and the only environment it runs on is OS X.

I heard it's possible to run virtualized OS X on Windows (like in VMware), but it's against Apple's EULA - it's allowed to run OS X on Apple HW only.

Comment: So, having an iOS (iMac or Mac Book) I can and I may develop legally and if I want to test it then I must have one iPad. Thank you.

Comment: **iOS is not iMac or MBP** ... thats OSX ;)

Comment: iOS is iPad and iPhone

Answer (score 0):

you need to run OSX

- officially only a mac can run OSX: so yes
- unofficially: a pc can be made to run OSX: so it *CAN* be done